# Displaying DOS error message using Rhino/JavaScript/Java

Tags: java, javascript, batch-file, rhino

I am trying to run a DIR command using a program similar to Rhino language (the program is using Java/JavaScript).

If there are any syntax error or any other error, I want to print out the error message using the function below:

```
function CatchDOSError()
{

var ErrorMSG = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir \\C:\Test\Data /s /b /a-D > c:\Test\fileRunDIR.txt").getErrorStream()));

while (( ErrorMSG.readLine()) != null) 
 {
println(ErrorMSG);
}
ErrorMSG.close();
```

}

If I run this function, all what I get as an output in the console is: "java.io.BufferedReader@71fbs019".

If I run the DOS command from CMD manually, the error message is "The System cannot find the path". This is the error message which I want it to be displayed using the function above. Not sure if there are conversion issues or something wrong with my function.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you just trying to get a list of files in a directory, or are you specifically writing a front-end to CMD?

Comment: Elliott Frisch was able to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
while (( ErrorMSG.readLine()) != null) {
  println(ErrorMSG);
}
```

You discard the line after checking it wasn't null and then print the Reader itself (which doesn't override `toString()` and isn't the line). I think you wanted,

```
var line = "";
while (( line = ErrorMSG.readLine()) != null) {
  println(line);
}
```